# I have been trying to draw on a new layer with drawing tablet without much luck

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

I have an huion inspiroy 610pro v2 tablet and have been trying to draw on a new layer without much luck. I have been able to draw strokes with a mouse yet they will not place down. On the tablet end, no strokes will show up or be saved. I have tried to turn on/off various input settings and still have no luck. [image]